# How to clear "Recent Test Suites" list in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

Selenium IDE doesn't remove old entries from the Recent Test Suites list even when the files are not found anymore. How can they be removed?

Edit:
Nowadays one can do it easily with `Options -> Clear history -> Clear recent test suites history`

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this too and found it here:

- in the Firefox address bar, type `about:config`
- in the search bar, type `recentTestCases`
- for each line: hit right mouse button for the context menu, and click `Reset`

[image: Selenium IDE plugin for Firefox about:config]